# detecting only slow moving objects using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, motion-detection

I am using OpenCV for motion detection and using back ground subtraction algo for this. I got the following code from net.

```
cv::Mat frame;
    cv::Mat back;
    cv::Mat fore;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    bg.nmixtures = 3;
    bg.bShadowDetection = false;
const int history = 5;
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg (history,nmixtures,bShadowDetection);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

    cv::namedWindow("Frame");
    cv::namedWindow("Background");

    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        bg.operator ()(frame,fore);
        bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
        cv::erode(fore,fore,cv::Mat());
        cv::dilate(fore,fore,cv::Mat());
        cv::findContours(fore,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        cv::drawContours(frame,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
        cv::imshow("Frame",frame);
        cv::imshow("Background",back);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
```

So can i set a threshold so that if the change in new and old frame is more than the threshold then dont do anything. Or may be some other algorithm that should suit my situation of capturing only slow moving object.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the history value (increase it) in the mixture of gaussian model if you wish to detect slow moving objects.

Comment: I tried that actually , but in that case it captures both slow and fast movement.

Comment: You can compute for two thresholds and subtract the two to get the motion for only the slow one in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use moving average of frames instead of using every frame as input for BG subtraction. Or use moving average to output of BG  subtraction, then binarize by thresholding.

See [addWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) and [moving Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) (see Cumulative moving average).

Integration will reduce influence of fast changes.